# Simple expression throws "Undefined control sequence"

Tags: math-mode

I have a simple expression in my text which refuses to compile and I don't know why:

```
...\textit{isInterestedIn(Class$\<$? extends ContentChange$\>$ changeClass)}...
```

The complete error statement goes like this:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \<
l.298 ...? extends ContentChange$\>$ changeClass)}
mit einem der \textit{Tex...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

I don't really understand, what's the problem here.

Comment: What do you want. Type only `$<$` and `$y$`. Or do you looking for something like: `\langle\text{extends ContentChange}\rangle`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command (called *control sequence*) `\<` is unknown. `\` means the start of a control sequence. Write `$<$` or `$\backslash<$` instead, the latter if you really need a backslash .

Comment: Thanks man, that did the trick for me. However, I'm a little curious why Texmaker returned me this expression from it's math character table...?!

Comment: One can use `\left<` and `\right>` as abbreviations for `\left\langle` and `\right\rangle`; even `\bigl<` and `\bigr>` are legal. But `\<` has always been undefined in LaTeX (other than in the `tabbing` environment).

Comment: -1 from me for suggesting $\backslah$ for text mode backslash. For obtaining a backslash in text mode, use `\textbackslash`; for using `<` and `>` in text mode, use `T1` font encoding (or an opentype font).

Comment: @Aditya: thanks for explaining the downvote. You could add your comment as answer. Btw. I assume the backslash is not needed at all: See for example `public boolean isAnnotationPresent(Class<? extends Annotation> annotationClass)` [here in Java documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html). And for deciding choosing math `<` or text `<` I don't see much information of the OP about the context such as encoding or desired shape of `<`, so I just fixed and explained.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use math mode to get text < and >. A simpler solution is to either use `T1` font encoding, or an opentype font (with lualatex or xetex). For example, with `pdflatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\textit{<text>}
\end{document}
```

or with `lualatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\begin{document}
\textit{<text>}
\end{document}
```